# How to check the user password id same as given password in mysqli Code below which is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if(array_key_exists('signinbtn',$_POST)){
    if(!$_POST['email']){
        echo'<p>please enter your email</p><br>';
    } elseif(!$_POST['password']){
        echo'<p>please enter your password</p><br>';
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT `id` 
                    FROM `users` 
                    WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $_POST['email'])."'";
        $query_result = mysqli_query($link , $query);
        if($get_row = mysqli_num_rows($query_result) == 0){
            echo'Email is not registered';
        } else {
            $post_query = "SELECT `password` 
                            FROM `users` 
                            WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $_POST['email'])."'";
            if($resultforsignup = mysqli_query($link , $post_query)){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultforsignup) == $_POST['password']){
                    echo'success';
                } else {
                    echo'password does not meet';
                }
            } else {
                echo'error while sign in';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm learning mysql
Now the problem is I want to check user password is given password same or not. please solve this
here is the website [mridul.ml](https://mridul.ml)

Comment: you can select more than one column in a select so those 2 selects can be written as `SELECT id, password FROM ...`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: We have 2021 and people still escape data instead of using parametrized queries that avoid interpolating data in SQL query strings altogether?!

Comment: ___Definitely needs a rethink___ `if ( mysqli_num_rows($resultforsignup) == $_POST['password'] ){` the number of rows returned from a query will almost definitely never be equal to the password entered by a user

Comment: RiggsFolly i didn't use any security here i just want to not escape the data when user write data like codex'city as a result if you use ' this it will stop at the last of codex city will not include and i know i have to use md5 or anything else to store the password i just said how can i check the user password same as given password

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the number of rows returned from your query with the password.  So unless the password is 1, it won't work.

As mentioned in the comments, you should use prepared statments for your query.

Also, you are apparently storing the raw text of the password in the database.  You should never do this.  You should use a salt and secure hash for passwords.  Fortunately, PHP has some convenient functions for this purpose.  Store the passwords in the database using [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and then when you get the password from the database use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to see if it is correct.  This prevents attackers from just getting all your users passwords if they get access to your database.